# Extract only specific rows and columns from a table (td) in BeautifulSoup, python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to scrape data from a website and write it to CSV. The sample code contains "column names" and "values".

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <!-- required First 3 column names-->
      <tr>
        <td></td>   
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" title=" Number">Number</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" colspan="2" title=" Code ">CODE</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;">Name</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="Category ">Category</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="Variation ">Variation</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- required -->
      <tr class="success">
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="/Number/3259">3259</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:125px;height:60px;vertical-align:middle;" <a href="/CODE/ABC123">ABC123</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a title="CODE ABC123" href="/CODE/ABC123">LAND </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="success">3 - Design Reference</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="success">2 - Production Item</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- not-required -->
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
          <div id="BMCRL_36" class="collapse">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a class="list-group-item">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> Number 3259 - Reference Number ABC123</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
              </a>
              <a class="list-group-item">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">CODE ABC123 </h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- required -->
      <tr class="">
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="/Number/3260">3260</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:125px;height:60px;vertical-align:middle;" <a href="/CODE/XYZ453">XYZ453</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a title="CODE XYZ453" href="/CODE/XYZ453">WATER </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="success">3 Control Reference</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="success">2 Item</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

> The output should be like

1. Column names from First **'td'** tag when I use this

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   soup = BeautifulSoup(open('code.html'),'lxml')
   col = soup.find('tr').find_all('td')
   for c in col:
       print(c.get_text())
   ```

   all the columns are printed. Instead i need only,

   `['Number', 'Code', 'Name']`
2. I don't need **'tr'** which contains "colspan" *(3rd tr)*
3. Also remove last two column values,

   ```
    tr = soup.findChildren('tr')  
    for t in tr:  
        td = t.findChildren('td')   
        for child in td:   
           print(child.text)
   ```

   again i get the whole data including the columns and values, what I expect is

   ```
    ['3259', 'ABC123', 'LAND']
              and
    ['3260', 'XYZ453','WATER']
   ```

   by removing
        `['3 - Design Reference','2 - Production Item']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice the results of `find_all()` to get only relevant columns and cells. In order to get only relevant rows, check the presence of the `class` attribute.

Working sample:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
your HTML here
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

headers = [c.get_text() for c in soup.find('tr').find_all('td')[1:4]]

data = [[cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')[1:4]]
        for row in soup.find_all("tr", class_=True)]

print(headers)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['Number', 'CODE', 'Name']
[['3259', 'ABC123', 'LAND'], ['3260', 'XYZ453', 'WATER']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Alecxe's helpful answer, for a more readable and Pythonic approach, list comprehensions can be utilised to exclude specific BS4 results (including those not meeting set criteria).
Here is an example:

```
rows = [ row for row in soup.findAll('tr') if 'adsbygoogle' not in row.text ]
```

This then creates a new list of rows including only the required elements.